# How do you copy lines that contain specific strings from a .csv file to a .txt file in Python using %BASH?

Tags: python, linux

Copy all lines from example.csv that contain "joe", "john,11", into a file called example.txt.

Comment: So your question was - How do i read from a file? How do find if a string contains another string? How do I write to a file? And which is it, python, or bash?

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep if you do not mind the example.txt getting overwritten

```
grep -e 'joe' -e 'john,11'  example.csv  >  example.txt
```

If you want to append just use `>>` instead of `>`